# windows phone default decimal seperator dot (.) instead of comma (,)

Tags: c#, windows-phone

in app.xaml.cs in the  private void InitializePhoneApplication() , i have written this code but instead of having the dot as the default decimal seperator it continues to have the comma, any ideas?, any help would be apreciated

```
CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = customCulture;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is done on a different thread from the one that initializes the application.

I would recommand you leave the current culture to it's default and specify an InvariantCulture when required: `myNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`